# how to transpose columns in a kdb table?

Tags: kdb

I would like to transpose a table:

Eg.

```
tab:([]date:10?(2023.09.01;2023.09.02;2023.09.04);algo:10?`A`B`C`D;timeZone:10?(00:00:00;00:05:00;00:10:00);cnt:(10?10))
update total:sum (cnt) by algo,date from `tab
update proportion:(cnt%total) by algo,date from `tab
```

I would like to see the table similar to below ( proportion I made up)
formula is sum of the count / total number of the day for each algo.

```
date          algo  proportionIn0s  proportionIn5m   proportionIn10m
2023.09.01    `a        0.3              0.5            0.2
2023.09.01     `b          0.4            0.4            0.2
2023.09.01    `c           0.2             0.3            0.5
2023.09.05    `a            0.4             0.1           0.5
2023.09.05    `b              0.6           0.2             0.2
```

What I got is something like this but it may miss if the algo is missing in the left part of the join

```
(select algo,date,fivem:proportion from tab where timeZone = 0D00:05:00.000000000) lj (2!select algo,date,prop0s:proportion from tab where timeZone = 0D00:00:00.000000000)
```

Comment: Could you explain how you calculated the vales in the proportion columns in your output? e.g. Algo A only has 1 entry on the 1st of September - in the 05:00 timezone. How do you arrive at the values 0.3 0.5 0.2 for A on the 1st?

This may be of use to you: https://code.kx.com/q/kb/pivoting-tables/

Comment: becuase i used the random number: the porportion may not be the same in your case.   I made the proportion up.  proportion = sum count / total count by that algo in that particular date

Comment: Random data is fine for creating sample data, but please don't randomise your expected output. How can others be expected to help when we don't know what to aim for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on @cillianreilly's comment, you can achieve this as following:

```
q)tab:([]date:10?(2023.09.01;2023.09.02;2023.09.04);algo:10?`A`B`C`D;timeZone:10?(00:00:00;00:05:00;00:10:00);cnt:(10?10));
q)update total:sum (cnt) by algo,date from `tab;
q) update proportion:(cnt%total) by algo,date from `tab;

q)tab 
date       algo timeZone cnt total proportion
---------------------------------------------
2023.09.01 B    00:10:00 8   14    0.5714286
2023.09.04 A    00:00:00 1   6     0.1666667
2023.09.01 A    00:05:00 9   9     1
2023.09.02 B    00:05:00 5   5     1
2023.09.01 C    00:10:00 4   10    0.4
2023.09.01 B    00:00:00 6   14    0.4285714
2023.09.01 C    00:05:00 6   10    0.6
2023.09.04 D    00:10:00 1   9     0.1111111
2023.09.04 D    00:05:00 8   9     0.8888889
2023.09.04 A    00:10:00 5   6     0.8333333

q)show P:asc exec distinct timeZone from tab
`s#00:00:00 00:05:00 00:10:00

q)tab lj exec `proportionIn0s`proportionIn5m`proportionIn10m!(timeZone!proportion)P by date,algo from tab
date       algo timeZone cnt total proportion proportionIn0s proportionIn5m proportionIn10m
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2023.09.01 B    00:10:00 8   14    0.5714286  0.4285714                     0.5714286
2023.09.04 A    00:00:00 1   6     0.1666667  0.1666667                     0.8333333
2023.09.01 A    00:05:00 9   9     1                         1
2023.09.02 B    00:05:00 5   5     1                         1
2023.09.01 C    00:10:00 4   10    0.4                       0.6            0.4
2023.09.01 B    00:00:00 6   14    0.4285714  0.4285714                     0.5714286
2023.09.01 C    00:05:00 6   10    0.6                       0.6            0.4
2023.09.04 D    00:10:00 1   9     0.1111111                 0.8888889      0.1111111
2023.09.04 D    00:05:00 8   9     0.8888889                 0.8888889      0.1111111
2023.09.04 A    00:10:00 5   6     0.8333333  0.1666667                     0.8333333
```

If you only want the value for the current row, add `timeZone` to your by clause i.e.

```
q)tab lj exec `proportionIn0s`proportionIn5m`proportionIn10m!(timeZone!proportion)P by date,algo,timeZone from tab
    date       algo timeZone cnt total proportion proportionIn0s proportionIn5m proportionIn10m
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    2023.09.01 B    00:10:00 8   14    0.5714286                                0.5714286
    2023.09.04 A    00:00:00 1   6     0.1666667  0.1666667
    2023.09.01 A    00:05:00 9   9     1                         1
    2023.09.02 B    00:05:00 5   5     1                         1
    2023.09.01 C    00:10:00 4   10    0.4                                      0.4
    2023.09.01 B    00:00:00 6   14    0.4285714  0.4285714
    2023.09.01 C    00:05:00 6   10    0.6                       0.6
    2023.09.04 D    00:10:00 1   9     0.1111111                                0.1111111
    2023.09.04 D    00:05:00 8   9     0.8888889                 0.8888889
    2023.09.04 A    00:10:00 5   6     0.8333333                                0.8333333
```